# Why did the Great Wizard grow his beard?

Tags: the-worst-witch

At the end of the first season of *The Worst Witch* (2017), the Great Wizard has a very short beard. However, by his next appearance in the second season, perhaps a few months later, he has quite a long white beard and mustache, a good two feet. It's clear that this has to be intentional, because without magical assistance, a beard would not grow that far in under a year. This is particularly interesting, because it seemed like his short beard was a sign of him being "modern," as wizards go, having arrived in a cab and so forth, he eschewed the traditional long wizard beard.

So why did the Great Wizard choose to grow his beard out so abruptly?

Comment: Because Wizards have long beards sometimes you just cant escape tradition.  Wizards staffs also have a knob on the end.